# Set the function itself to the url in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I am new to AJAX. Recently, I read a block of code that set url to the function itself. In this case, it is get Path. Normally, we will set url to other pages to get data or something. I do not know what it means to set url to the calling function itself. Could you help answer my question?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPath()
        {
            var startLat = $('#startLat').val();
            var startLng = $('#startLng').val();
            var desLat = $('#desLat').val();
            var desLng = $('#desLng').val();
            var departure = $('#departure').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getPath",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "startLat": startLat, "startLng": startLng, "desLat": desLat, "desLng": desLng, "departure": departure},
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.success) {
                        $('#result').val(response.data);
                        console.log('Reponse.success is true');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Response.success is false');
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: "I do not know what it means to set url to the calling function itself." I don't think anyone else does, either. What do you mean? Please provide the exact code and tell us what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getPath()  <-- function 
    url: "getPath",  <-- string
```

They are not related. Only thing in common is the developer had the same name. The page will post to some location called `getPath` on the server.

Comment: In the html file, I cannot find getPath variable except the getPath() function. I do not know what it happens.

Comment: There is no variable, it is a string see the quotes?  `-->  "getPath" <--`

Comment: But I can not find any string called getPath in the html file. The only one I can find is getPath() function.

Comment: yes. you are right. BTW, you can review the source code of the page online. 54.201.92.181

Comment: If you add a breakpoint in your js function getPath(), and use chrome's developer tool, you will see in the Network section that the ajax goes to `http://54.201.92.181/getPath`.

Comment: Yeah. I may get your point. There may be some servlet whose name is getPath.

Comment: @mridula thanks, I got the point. It is really interesting to me, a new comer to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean anything other than the fact that the url the POST request is being sent to happens to be "getPath". The function is probably named according to the route name on the server side, but renaming that function (and updating every place it is called accordingly) would have no effect, and you would have to leave the `url: "getPath"` as is. Changing that part would likely break something.

That `getPath` would be a relative url, so the request goes to something like: http://example.com/path/to/parent/of/current/page/getPath

Comment: yeah. I think your answer is reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

**suppose your HTML input URL**

```
 <input type="url"  id="web_url" value=""></input>
```

**Then you can get your URL**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getPath()
    {
        var startLat = $('#startLat').val();
        var startLng = $('#startLng').val();
        var desLat = $('#desLat').val();
        var desLng = $('#desLng').val();
        var departure = $('#departure').val();
        var url = $('#web_url').val();  // getting input URL by User 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url ,
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "startLat": startLat, "startLng": startLng, "desLat": desLat, "desLng": desLng, "departure": departure},
            success: function (response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    $('#result').val(response.data);
                    console.log('Reponse.success is true');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Response.success is false');
                }
            },
            error: function(e) {
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Comment: U first understand what user has asked and then put up answers.. and read the question well and the answers given by other users..Then devote anybody's effort..